# unix : search a file if a string is present between two patterns

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file, having a format, given below. I want to search if a word for e.g. 'hello' is present in line following schema and before the DocName. If it is present, how many such schema's have it?
How can I do this in one line using grep/awk/sed?

The expected output is: assuming I am searching if word 'hello' is present, then in  this case it is present in 1st, 2nd and 4th schema, so the output is 3, since we have three 'hello' present in three schemas. Note even if there are multiple occurrences of 'hello' in first schema, it is still counted as one.

```
:
:
:
DocName: abjrkj.txt
schema:
abs
askj
djsk
djsk
hello
adj
hello

DocName: abjrkj.txt
schema:
abs
askj
djsk
djsk
adj
hello

DocName: aasjrkj.txt
schema:
absasd
askjas
djsksa
djskasd
adjsg

DocName: ghhd.txt
schema:
absg
fdgaskj
dgdjsk
dgdfdjsk
drgadj
hello
:
:
:
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the above input?

Comment: @lanc make better example with various input and write expected example output

Comment: I have edited the question, have a look.

Comment: @Lanc: In the past you've accepted too few answers (3/16).

Comment: @lanc for counting wc is apropriate choice!

Comment: But how do I grep the text between the pattern:DocName

Comment: for this some awk user should intervene i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
awk -F '^DocName:' '/hello/ { ++i }
    END { print i }' file
```

If you absolutely require a one-line solution (why??) the whitespace can be condensed to just one space.

Comment: Thanks!! By one line, I was hinting towards a compact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sed solution:

```
sed ':a; N; s/\n/ /; $!ba; s/DocName/\n&/g' < file | sed -n '/DocName/{/hello/p}' | wc
```

This is algorithm: It puts whole file in pattern space with replacing all \n characters with space. Then before every DocName string puts \n. After that is piping throw searching Docname & hello finally prints 3 numbers from which first is asked. If you want to see printed lines omit | wc piping for test reasons. Maybe more elegant sed solution exists playing with pattern & hold space!

Answer (score 0):

Since your input file has schemas separated by blank lines you can use awk in paragraph mode and then it's simply:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/hello/{++c} END{print c}' file
3
```

Comment: as a newbie for awk, what is -v, RS=? In plans for awk too :) @ed-morton

Comment: `-v` is the flag to set an awk variable, `RS` is the Record Separator that defines what characters/strings/regexps separate records, and `RS=` or `RS=""` sets RS to the null char which tells awk that records are separated by blank lines.

Comment: tnx! btw that book about awk you mentioned yesterday have 4.th newest edition 2014, what to say, comparing our solutions your is with less characters & more readable. For walking walk, biking bike, enough! (car unneeded)